# css transition that executes first, then the rest of the css changes follow

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I am not sure how to explain this problem... It is more of a theoretical problem, how to make this...

On my header element I use:

```
transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out
```

When I scroll up it set's a class up and the header is shown with transition. If I scroll to the top or down it is hidden again with transition. This part works, so I didn't post all the css here.

I have this header on a webiste from the beggining, but when I show it on the sroll up, it is modified by css, some parts are hidden, some parts are different padding etc.

Problem is, this change of styles happens immediately and the easing transition does not of course.

When this small fixed header is shown, after it is fully shown the paddings etc. were allready corrected. But when the transition goes out of the screen, I first see that the header is changed to the default size and then it dissapears. Which is kind of logical, but I am wondering how can I delay the css changes until after the transition, is that possible?

Or is the only way to make another header that is hidden until I need it (that would make duplicate code), but would be much easier than taking it out of the flow, transforming it and hiding it again, because the transition out transformation is seen now.

Maybe I should use jquery transition and first do the transition and then change the css styles, when it is hidden?

Comment: You could use CSS animations instead. with 99% for animated value and all other set to default and in 100% set other rules value. Of course, would be easier to just use relevant transitionend event to set new CSS rules (or adding/removing class)

Comment: See e.g: http://fiddle.jshell.net/m8xuvk4d/